# Spring Cfg+Hibernate Cfg and Anotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I want to make a test with HQL but the mapping tables is with Annotations.
Hibernate configuration file is in the /WEB-INF/spring-config-ws.xml :::>

```
<!-- Activate transaction declarations with annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Property files application uses -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JNDI DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${dataSource.jndiName}" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>es.sergas.rprof.profesional.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.default_schema}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I run a list, I get that you do not find the hibernate cfg:
hibernate.cfg.xml not found

I just want to list a mapped class with annotations, but HQL

I feel my level of English is so low. Thank you

Comment: Where is your hibernate.cfg.xml is located in your file structure?

Comment: hibernate.cfg.xml file is inside the spring:
in /WEB-INF/spring-config-ws.xml and refers to this jdbc.properties. # Tomcat:
dataSource.jndiName=...

# Hibernate properties:
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider

# ORACLE
hibernate.default_schema=...
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `hibernate.cfg.xml` is inside `src/main/resources`, if the file is not there you need to specify the right location, so put it inside this folder that your problem will be solved.

> Note that we don’t have to explicitly mention the mapping or configuration or properties
>   files, because the Hibernate runtime looks for default filenames, such as hibernate.
>   cfg.xml or hibernate.properties, in the classpath and loads them. If we have a nondefault
>   name, make sure you pass that as an argument—like configure("my-hibcfg.
>   xml"), for example.